# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::map() in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

My product controller:

```
 public function category(Request $request, $name, $main){
          if($request->data){
            $explode_id = array_map('intval', explode(',', $request->data));
            $category_id = Category::where('name', $name)->value('id');
            if($category_id == "")
            {
              $all_categories_id = Category::pluck('id');
            }
            else
            {
            $all_categories_id = Category::where('parent_id', $category_id)->pluck('id');
            $all_categories_id->push($category_id);
            }
            $product_id = Product::where('name', 'like','%'.$main.'%')->whereIn('id', $explode_id)->pluck('id');
            $id = ProductCategory::whereIn('product_id', $product_id)->whereIn('category_id', $all_categories_id)->pluck('id');
            $products = Product::find($id); 
          }
          else{
              $category_id = Category::where('name', $name)->value('id');
              if($category_id == "")
              {
                $all_categories_id = Category::pluck('id');
              }
              else
              {
              $all_categories_id = Category::where('parent_id', $category_id)->pluck('id');
              $all_categories_id->push($category_id);
              }
              $product_id = Product::where('name', 'like','%'.$main.'%')->pluck('id');
              $id = ProductCategory::whereIn('product_id', $product_id)->whereIn('category_id', $all_categories_id)->pluck('id');
              $products = Product::find($id);
          }    

            //Categories Name in Sidebar
            $category = ProductCategory::whereIn('product_id', $id)->pluck('parent_id');
            $category_name = Category::whereIn('id', $category)->pluck('name');

            //Categories Name in dropdown
            $main_categories = Category::where('parent_id', '0')->pluck('name'); 

            $user = Auth::user();
            $directory = 'uploads/users/images/'.$user->id;
            $main_categories = Category::where('parent_id', '0')->pluck('name');
            if (is_dir($directory)) {
            $files = scandir ($directory);
            $img_file = $directory.'/'.$files[2];
            $user['front_img'] = $img_file;
            }
            $profile = $user['front_img'];
            //Product Image Mapping     
            $products->map(function ($product) {
            $directory = 'uploads/products/images/'.$product->id;
            $brand = Brand::select('name')->where('id', '=', $product->brand)->pluck('name');
            $brand_name = $brand->first(function($value, $key) {
              return $key == 'name';
            });
            if (is_dir($directory)) {
              $files = scandir ($directory);
              $img_file = $directory.'/'.$files[2];
              $product['front_img'] = $img_file;
              $product['brand'] = $brand_name;
              return $product;
            }
              return $product;
            });

          return view('pages/product', compact('main_categories', 'profile', 'products', 'name', 'category_name'));
        }
```

This is code in my product controller When i try to run this code it show the error here i used map() to map the products images and display it my view but why this error came ..Please any one help me..

Comment: Dude.... **Please consider some serious refactoring** (and maybe some PSR-2 guidelines). That would make it pretty obvious that e.g. `$products` that you're trying to run `map()` on is a single `Model` and not a `Collection` (which you would expect given that variable name...).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's because `map()` does not exist.

```
$products = Product::find($id);
```

is just short for

```
$products = Product::where('id', $id)->first();
```

So you're only getting one single `Product` model back. Then you're trying to call `map()` on it, which only exists on `Collection`s that are returned if the results contains multiple datasets / Models. But you're explicitly asking for a single one. So you're getting `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` in response and then try to call `map()` on that. Since this method does not exist, Laravel tries to defer to `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`, and if does not find that method there, it bombs out with the above mentioned Exception.

So: There is only one `$products`, no need to map over it, just use it directly. Also, this would be even more clear if you called it `$product` instead of `$products`.